# java.lang.ClassCastException during action chaining - from Struts 1 to Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts, struts2-interceptors

We have Struts 1 application.We need to migrate to Struts 2.
With minor change.We are not going to change anything in Action class.
We are using existing action class and Action Form.
Action is getting triggered without any issues.
But action chain is not working as expected.
We are using many values from LoginAction to FetchInboxAction. Both are using two different form.
Please find the sample struts.xml and error stack.
The chain action is not working for us.

Currently we are getting the below error:

```
225760 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler  - Exception occurred during processing request: com.InboxForm cannot be cast to com.LoginForm
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.InboxForm cannot be cast to com.LoginForm
at com.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:104)
at org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action.execute(Struts1Action.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.invokeMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:891)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1293)
at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethodWithDebugInfo(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMethodAccessor.callMethod(XWorkMethodAccessor.java:108)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1369)
at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:458)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil$2.execute(OgnlUtil.java:309)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.compileAndExecute(OgnlUtil.java:340)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:307)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:423)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:287)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:250)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionChainResult.execute(ActionChainResult.java:233)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:369)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:273)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:229)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DateTextFieldInterceptor.intercept(DateTextFieldInterceptor.java:125)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:244)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:564)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:81)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.SecurityAccessFilter.doFilter(SecurityAccessFilter.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

struts.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


<package name="PackageName" namespace="/"
                               extends="struts1-default">
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="LoginForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.LoginForm</param>
    <param name="name">LoginForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor name="InboxForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.InboxForm</param>
    <param name="name">InboxForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor-stack name="web">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="LoginForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>    


  <interceptor-stack name="web2">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>


<action name="LoginAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute" >
 <param name="className">com.LoginAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web"/>       
    <result name="success" type="chain">FetchInboxAction</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
 </action>

    <action name="FetchInboxAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute">
 <param name="className">com.FetchInboxAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web2"/>
    <result name="success">/sucess.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: The action chaining is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In struts.xml for `fetchInboxAction` all interceptors are called again due to this after executing `LoginAction` instead of invoking `FetchInboxAction` it invokes `LoginAction` with `InboxForm`.In Action class Action form is typed casted to `LoginForm` but in run time we got `FetchInboxForm`. This is due to wrong config.

After the below changes Action chin is working without any issue.

## Modified Struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


<package name="PackageName" namespace="/"
                               extends="struts1-default">
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="LoginForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.LoginForm</param>
    <param name="name">LoginForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor name="InboxForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.InboxForm</param>
    <param name="name">InboxForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor-stack name="web">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="LoginForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>    


  <interceptor-stack name="web2">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>


<action name="LoginAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute" >
 <param name="className">com.LoginAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web"/>       
    <result name="success" type="chain">FetchInboxAction</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
 </action>

    <action name="FetchInboxAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute">
 <param name="className">com.FetchInboxAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <result name="success">/sucess.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```