# Struts2 Migration from Struts1 using struts2-struts1-plugin

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I tried to migrate a Struts1 application to Struts2 application using `struts2-struts1-Plugin.jar`.

I have successfully migrated.But I have an issue with Action Chain. Action Chain is not working as expected. However, Action Redirect is working as expected.

If i provide action type as chain instead of executing the next action it calling the same action class,  while debugging i am able to see that inside struts2-struts1 pligin setClasname method called twice first time it is setting as correct class but for the second time it is setting as previous action class name that is reason wrong action class is triggered.

Can someone help me with this?

## Struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


<package name="PackageName" namespace="/"
                               extends="struts1-default">
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="LoginForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.LoginForm</param>
    <param name="name">LoginForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor name="InboxForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.InboxForm</param>
    <param name="name">InboxForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor-stack name="web">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="LoginForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>    


  <interceptor-stack name="web2">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>


<action name="LoginAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute" >
 <param name="className">com.LoginAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web"/>       
    <result name="success" type="chain">FetchInboxAction</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
 </action>

    <action name="FetchInboxAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute">
 <param name="className">com.FetchInboxAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web2"/>
    <result name="success">/sucess.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Chained actions are discouraged and S1 plugin should be already deprecated. The code if it's not working in such scenario shows less interest to the audience.

Comment: You need a `chain` interceptor. Also what Roman said.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a solution for my  problem i will post it soon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException during action chaining - from Struts 1 to Struts 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432333/java-lang-classcastexception-during-action-chaining-from-struts-1-to-struts-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In struts.xml for fetchInboxAction instead of providing full interceptor stack only the required form interceptor will be passes since the reaming interceptors are already invoked as part of this request.

After the below changes Action chin is working without any issue.

## Modified Struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>


<package name="PackageName" namespace="/"
                               extends="struts1-default">
<interceptors>
  <interceptor name="LoginForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.LoginForm</param>
    <param name="name">LoginForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor name="InboxForm" 
   class="com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor">
    <param name="className">com.InboxForm</param>
    <param name="name">InboxForm</param>
    <param name="scope">request</param>
  </interceptor>


  <interceptor-stack name="web">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="LoginForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>    


  <interceptor-stack name="web2">
    <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
  </interceptor-stack>

</interceptors>


<action name="LoginAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute" >
 <param name="className">com.LoginAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="web"/>       
    <result name="success" type="chain">FetchInboxAction</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
 </action>

    <action name="FetchInboxAction" class="org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action" method="execute">
 <param name="className">com.FetchInboxAction</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="InboxForm"/>
    <result name="success">/sucess.jsp</result>
    <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>


    </package>
</struts>
```